# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "¡qué fuerte!"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos, españa

Con frecuencia en España se usa la expresión "qué fuerte" (especialmente entre signos de exclamación, "¡qué fuerte!") cuando queremos mostrar nuestra sorpresa, incluso estupefacción ante un hecho dado, en un contexto coloquial:

> - ¿Te has enterado? María se ha casado con Juan.
>
> - **¡Qué fuerte!** Pero si en el instituto se llevaban fatal.

A veces incluso le añadimos un *me parece* para dejarlo en "¡qué fuerte me parece!".

A mí me parece una expresión hermana a la que usamos cuando decimos que una noticia es muy fuerte, en el sentido de indicar impacto. Pero aún así, veo curiosa la construcción fortaleza -> intensidad -> estupefacción.

En inglés [veo que tiene un equivalente](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/qu%C3%A9-fuerte.7611/) "gosh" o "oh my God/gosh!" pero lo que no consigo es encontrar documentación sobre su origen. ¿Alguien lo sabe? ¿Qué hipótesis podéis dar sobre ello? ¿Es convincente lo que planteo?

Comment: Venga, va otra de mis hipótesis sacada de la chistera. La concepción que yo tengo de esa expresión es que nació durante la década de los ochenta, en la movida madrileña. Apoyo la teoría basándome en mi propia experiencia, es de esas expresiones que recuerdo haber empezado a escuchar a partir de un determinado punto del tiempo y no antes. Sobre el origen, mi teoría es que surgió a raíz de las bebidas alcohólicas. Cuando bebes algo de mucha graduación dices que es muy fuerte, de ahí a que cualquier cosa que te impacte sea fuerte, un paso.

Comment: El sentido de "intenso" o "impactante" ya estaba presente a finales de la Edad Media, por lo menos: "¡O, buena gente, e qué fuerte cosa ésta!" (1411-12), "¡Qué fuerte lance!" (1630). A mí el salto de "intenso"/"impactante" a "sorprendente" me parece natural. Lo curioso es que otros idiomas romances solo hayan conservado el sentido positivo de "fuerte" en expresiones similares: [Che forte!](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cavoli-che-forte.1888978/) [Trop fort!](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cest-trop-fort.1231504/)

Comment: He preguntado el origen de *Che forte!* y *trop fort!* en [Italian.SE](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/etimologia-origine-dellespressione-che-forte) y [French.SE](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19301/origine-%C3%A9tymologie-de-l-expression-trop-fort). A ver si alguien sabe algo.

Comment: @Yay han tenido una muy buena acogida. A ver si producen respuestas interesantes.

Comment: En Colombia también usamos esa expresión, pero sin el Qué, se usa "Fuerte" en tono de imprensión o desánimo.

Comment: En Argentina no se usa, me desconcertó un poco cuando la descubrí, (junto con el 'Ahí va!' como expresión de asombro) en traducciones españolas de comics :-)

Comment: Algo muy común en Chile: _¡Fuerte lo tuyo!_, que significa más o menos "Lo que has dicho es muy grave".

Comment: @fedorqui Vi tu comentario, pero se me fue completamente el santo al cielo. ¡Perdón por el feo!

Comment: @Yay faltaría más : ) Lo bueno se hace esperar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por mi experiencia, creo que empezó a popularizarse a partir de la película "Regreso al Futuro". En ella Marty McFly emplea (en el inglés original) la expresión "That's heavy" cuando quiere referirse a algo que le ha impactado. En España esa expresión se tradujo por "¡qué fuerte!".

He aquí el [Google Ngram sobre el uso de "¡qué fuerte!" desde 1800 en los libros](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C2%A1qu%C3%A9%20fuerte!&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%C2%A1%20qu%C3%A9%20fuerte%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%C2%A1%20Qu%C3%A9%20fuerte%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C2%A1%20qu%C3%A9%20fuerte%20%21%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Comment: Nunca he confiado mucho en Google ngram, tal vez porque no lo entiendo bien, pero según google la expresión se usaba más en 1880 que en nuestros 80s. La película salió en 1985. https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=que+fuerte&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cque%20fuerte%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bque%20fuerte%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bque%20Fuerte%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQue%20fuerte%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Pero en esa busqueda se están incluyendo todas las frases en las que aparece "qué fuerte". No sólo aquellas en las que se usa como expresión de asombro. ¿Cómo distingue ngram entre "qué fuerte que era aquel soldado...." de "qué fuerte; ha salido disparado"

Comment: Usa este ngram en su lugar: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C2%A1qu%C3%A9+fuerte!&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%C2%A1%20qu%C3%A9%20fuerte%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%C2%A1%20Qu%C3%A9%20fuerte%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C2%A1%20qu%C3%A9%20fuerte%20%21%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Excelente.  Gracias por la respuesta. No creí que ngram fuera tan específico. Por eso dije que no lo entiendo bien todavía. :-)

Comment: Y fíjate que, según ese ngram, la expresión empezó a cobrar popularidad en 1987, poco más de un año después del estreno de la película en España (2 de Diciembre de 1985), así que no sé a ciencia cierta si la peli fue la génesis de esa expresión, pero de lo que no cabe duda es que contribuyó a popularizarla.

Comment: ¡Qué fuerte! La verdad es que me he quedado la mar de sorprendido con esta respuesta. Mirando en los resultados del Ngram y comparando su uso antes y después del 1985 se ve claramente como se introduce este significado. De hecho, en el libro "El Léxico en el Español Actual: Uso y Norma" se menciona: _FUERTE: este adjetivo se emplea hoy mucho, sobre todo entre jóvenes, de forma poco apropiada y muy polisémica por raro, llamativo, importante, anómalo, violento..._. Luego debió ir aumentando su base social de uso hasta convertirse en una expresión usada por todos.

Comment: Busqué los subtítulos de la película en distintas modalidades del castellano. La versión de España dice: _¿Estás intentando decirme que mi madre está colada por mí? / - Exacto. / - Esto es **muy fuerte**._, mientras que la de Argentina dice: _¿Está tratando de decirme que mi madre está enamorada de mí? / - Precisamente. / - Eso es **pesado**._. Curiosamente, la versión de Colombia también usa "fuerte", mientras que la de México usa "pesado".

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Nota: esta es una breve hipótesis sobre su desarrollo histórico. Con respecto al auge moderno de la expresión, la propuesta de mcleod_ideafix me parece interesante.</sup>

Aunque *fuerte* se utiliza principalmente por el sector juvenil (sobre todo la juventud española), no está lejos del significado tradicional de la palabra. El latín "fortis" ya poseía algunos significados del mismo campo semántico que la expresión actual, tales como "intenso", "sustancioso", "drástico" o "épico", aunque no todas estas expresiones se aplicaban a hazañas tanto como a la comida, a la percepción sensorial (luces, sonido) o al estilo literario<sup>1</sup>. El salto mental de algo intenso para, por ejemplo, los sentidos, a algo intenso para las emociones parece más que probable. Si una salsa es fuerte, impacta sobre las papilas gustativas; si una luz es fuerte, impacta sobre los ojos; y si una noticia es fuerte, impacta sobre las emociones.

A finales de la Edad Media ya aparecen algunos ejemplos de la palabra "fuerte" usada en el sentido de "intenso" o "impactante" en un plano emocional:

> "[E]l Rey, abaxada la cabeça, estovo callando un grand rato e dixo:
>
> — ¡O **qué fuerte cosa** e dura sería a mí conversar con tal mortal enemigo mío, que me quitó la lunbre de mis ojos!"
>
> García de Salazar, Lope (1471 - 1476). *Istoria de las bienandanzas e fortunas*

También hay varios ejemplos en el CORDE de "fuerte lance" en los años 1630, 1676, 1687, 1740 y 1764:

> "En buen empeño se halla
>   la autoridad con el brío.
>   En **fuerte lance** me veo
>   con mi yerno y con mi amigo."
>
> Bances Candamo, Francisco (1687). *Por su rey y por su dama*

La RAE describe [lance](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Mrp6d72) como "suceso, acontecimiento, situación interesante o notable", por lo que no puede ser físicamente "fuerte": solo queda la interpretación de "intenso".

Curiosamente, la misma expresión existe en italiano ([*che forte!*](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cavoli-che-forte.1888978/)) y en francés ([*trop fort!*](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cest-trop-fort.1231504/)), aunque en ambos idiomas solo se conservó la acepción positiva, esto es: "genial", "alucinante". He preguntado sobre el origen de la expresión en ambos idiomas: en el [sitio italiano](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/etimologia-origine-dellespressione-che-forte) no se apoya la idea de que guarde relación con el étimo latino (aunque yo no estoy de acuerdo con esa conclusión), mientras que en [el francés](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19301/origine-%C3%A9tymologie-de-l-expression-trop-fort) sí se hace un mayor seguimiento de su etimología. Dice [@SurvenantLazurite](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/3177/survenant-lazurite) en [su respuesta](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19358/10449):

> Se usa también para aquello que *expresa un poder de orden intelectual o moral*, aplicado a una cosa, y *que sorprende o choca por su carácter insólito o excesivo. Sinónimos: exagerado, escandaloso, inadmisible, increíble*, en expresiones coloquiales: *C'est fort, un peu fort, trop fort; le plus fort est que; c'est un peu fort de café* [= difícil de admitir o creer, exagerado]; *c'est plus fort que de jouer au bouchon* [= increíble, sorprendente]. ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fort), III, B, 4.).

Según la misma respuesta, se reporta desde el siglo XIV el sentido de "fort" de excesivo o exagerado, y desde 1692 en la expresión "c'est fort". También se usaba en francés "fort" para describir lo que va más allá de lo normal por extensión, según el autor, de "más acentuado/intenso que los demás", para más tarde adquirir el sentido connotativo de "mejor que los demás" o "mejor de lo que el hablante se esperaba".

Me parece que la expresión española puede haber seguido un desarrollo similar al francés, aunque más limitado en sus connotaciones. Si "¡qué fuerte!" expresa algo positivo o negativo suele ir definido por el contexto:

> ¡He ganado la lotería! ¡Qué fuerte, no me lo puedo creer!
>   Se han filtrado fotos del presidente sobornando a un juez. ¡Qué fuerte, lo que hay que ver!

Lo que es seguro es que expresa sorpresa, intensidad, exageración y/o incredulidad, y en este sentido está muy cerca de las expresiones italiana y francesa.

---

<sup>1: Dizionario latino Olivetti, de la respuesta de Alessandro Omano en Italian.SE</sup>

Comment: Me quito el sombrero una vez más ante tu capacidad de profundizar en una respuesta. Ahora es tarde para digerirla en su justa medida, lo haré cuando el cerebro esté más despierto para disfrutarla. ¡Gracias!